# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: begin end function pragma procedure

Tags: oracle-apex

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY ECOM_LOGIN
AS 
    FUNCTION AUTHENTICATE(
          P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2 ,
          P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN BOOLEAN
    IS
    V_RESULT INTEGER := 0;
    L_PASSWORD VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN
    SELECT PASSWORD
    INTO L_PASSWORD
    FROM MY_USERS
    WHERE (UPPER (USERNAME) = UPPER(P_USERNAME)
    OR PHONE_NUMBER = P_USERNAME)
    AND PIN = 'Y';

    IF L_PASSWORD = P_PASSWORD THEN
        RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE 
        RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
    END AUTHENTICATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

A closing "END" keyword is missing from the package body:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY ECOM_LOGIN
AS 
    FUNCTION AUTHENTICATE(
          P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2 ,
          P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN BOOLEAN
    IS
    V_RESULT INTEGER := 0;
    L_PASSWORD VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN
    SELECT PASSWORD
    INTO L_PASSWORD
    FROM MY_USERS
    WHERE (UPPER (USERNAME) = UPPER(P_USERNAME)
    OR PHONE_NUMBER = P_USERNAME)
    AND PIN = 'Y';

    IF L_PASSWORD = P_PASSWORD THEN
        RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE 
        RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
    END AUTHENTICATE;
-- line below is needed
END ECOM_LOGIN;
```

As a side note, a password should **never be stored in clear text**. Plenty of examples on how to store password on the internet, here is [one](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/storing-passwords-in-the-database-9i) (old it shows exactly what the point is.